# Custom alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, customdialog

I want to build a custom alert dialog with a checkbox at the title field of the AlertDialog as shown below.

[image]

What i have already have is this(check box is not visible, sorry for that):

[image]

How to get the check box here at the title field.?
Also on selecting "All" options, all the other options should be selected.?

Comment: My suggestion is to create a fully customable dialog, for example in your dialog only the content is custom, but you can create a full custom dialog, [here is the offical ducumentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout). So you have to create the dialog with custom title and custom content. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As kameny suggested you can go with custom dialog. You have to design  a layout for that dialog as below

Textview Checkbox
Listview

You can remove the dialog title using `dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

Add listener to the checkbox and check whether the checkbox is selected or not. If it is selected please put a loop for items in the listview and change the checkbox status of each item in the listview. After that refresh the listview using notifydatasetchanged()

Comment: Can u suggest from posts which i can refer to populate checkbox thru listview.?

Comment: You can refer following link (http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2012/04/milti-selection-listview-android-with.html)

Comment: thank you. i ahve also stuck with another problem. can u help on it. here is my another question.? :::http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645911/android-inflating-views-of-tab-view